# Faraday's criterion (The magnitude of Electric field is proportional to the number of field lines)

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

According to Halliday et al, the magnitude of Electric field is proportional to the number of lines per unit area perpendicular to the field.

My book (Halliday et al) states that this criterion, called Faraday's criterion, is helpful to draw field lines in a space region, but I can't understand why the area must be proportional to the electric field.
In my opinion, I think it is important because if the area is not perpendicular to the field, it is impossibile to collect all the field lines on the surface.
Then I want to know if this criterion is valid only if the magnitude of electric field is constant everywhere on the surface or not.

If I assume there is an electric field in a space region with magnitude and direction which are not the same for each point, how do I apply this criterion?

I hope someone can help me. I feel discouraged by now and I would like to learn more.

Comment: I  have Googled "Faraday's criterion" and have come up with nothing. Can you cite a reference?

Comment: There is a field line passing through every point so there is an infinite number of field lines passing through any unit area (unless it is parallel to the field lines, in which case zero pass through). Field lines make for good visualizations but they are a bad way to quantify the field.

Comment: @G.Smith Agree that field lines are a useful visualization and that they certainly don't quantify the field. But wouldn't you say that the relative density of the lines between two different areas gives a sense of the relative strength of the field in those areas?

Comment: @BobD I don’t see how any sensible “density of lines” can be defined; it’s infinite. What happens is that people *draw* a finite number of lines and vary the density of those to indicate the field strength, which *is* well-defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the term "Faraday's criterion", but what is being referred to here is field line density. Density (in this context) is something that occurs at a given point in space and can certainly vary over an area or volume. Technically it does not refer to some trait of a given volume or area. If we casually say a given volume or area has a certain density, we only mean that that is the density on average over that volume or area. A "unit area" is mentioned here only to convey the concept of density, because density is in lines *per unit area*. Of course, if a field varies over a given area, we must be careful to note that.

Comment: I think you helped me! I guess I can't calculate density if the field lines are not distributed uniformly on the surface. So I guess I have to adopt the infinitesimal approach to know the magnitude of the electric field in each point of a surface subject to a variable electric field.

Comment: What about the electric field which must be perpendicular to electric field?

Answer (score 1):

Without further explanation, the statement that fields are proportional to the number of field lines crossing a perpendicular surface is nonsense, because for each point of the space there is a field line. Therefore, independently on the intensity of the field, one would count an infinite number of points and of field lines.

The necessary specification which is needed to provide meaning to that statement is that, **when drawing field lines**, it is necessary to choose a finite number of field lines. If one starts choosing a finite number of equally spaced points on a surface where the field has the same intensity (in symmetric cases, on a planar section of the surface, for 2D drawings), field equations will rule how the chosen lines will be continued in the space.

In the whole space where the field is solenoidal (its divergence is zero, which is the case of magnetic field and electric field in regions without charges) we can choose a  *flux tube* i.e. a volume made by two surfaces locally orthogonal to the field and a lateral surface coinciding with field lines. The flux through such a volume is zero, as well as the flux through the lateral surface and, as a consequence, the fluxes through the two orthogonal surfaces have the same absolute value (conservation of flux along flux tubes). Therefore, the largest is the surface, the smallest the field. If only a finite number of lines has been drawn, the number of lines per unit area of an orthogonal surface will be  proportional to the field intensity.

That is the reason for such a **drawing recipe**. It  provides a simple way to estimate space variations of field intensity by visual inspection of a good drawing of field lines.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have not been accurate to explain that the Faraday's criterion is valid only if we are drawing a finite number of field lines. Now I want to ask you why the surface must be perpendicular. The second question is: if I want to apply this criterion, must I check if the field lines are equally spaced, right? The criterion has sense only if the field is constant everywhere on the surface, I guess.

Comment: @AngeloGiannuzzi The orthogonality is required by the definition of flux (there is a scalar product, therefore it is the projection of the surface on a plane orthogonal to the field lines which contributes to the integral. About the second question, I am not sure I have understood it. One is interested to the local behavior of the field.  In order to extract information on the field from the flux, the latter has to be evaluated on a surface small enough to have small variations of the field over the whole surface.

Comment: Scusa ma lei è italiano?

Comment: @AngeloGiannuzzi Yes, but the official language on this site is english :-)

Comment: Great! Do you are any kind of professor? I am an engineering student. I am studying for my physics exam and I would like to know more and more. My colleagues think I am exaggerated but I am curious.

Comment: Anyway about the second question, density is a concept we can apply only if there is a uniform distribution of lines within a volume. So in this case if the field is variabile on a surface I guess I have to use the infinitesimal approach to know the electric field in each point of the surface because I cannot apply the Faraday's approach to the whole surface (density makes sense only with a uniform distribution of lines).

Comment: About the first question, if the field is not perpendicular to the surface there is less quantity of lines which can go through the surface itself, so if I am interested to know the magnitude of the electric field in a region of the space (not in a generic area of space), I must check if the area in each point is perpendicular to the field. Otherwise I will not know the value of the magnitude of the field in the interested region but in an area within the space (ex. a square piece of paper not perpendicular to the field).

Comment: @AngeloGiannuzzi counting field lines is always used to say something about the field *locally*. It is not a substitute for analytical o numerical  methods. It is a semi-quantitative method to extract quickly information from a figure. However, understanding how it works is a good exercise to understand fields, fluxes and field lines. You could check my claim by looking at the field lines of a point-like charge  (radial lines starting or ending at the charge position). Can you verify the $\frac{1}{r^2}$ behavior of the field by counting field lines?

Comment: For ex. If we apply the criterion to a point charge, positive or negative, we must be careful to choose a spherical surface concentric with the charge instead of a flat surface because in this second case we cannot collect all the lines that go radially around the charge. Is it right?

Comment: @AngeloGiannuzzi It is not necessary to collect all the lines. Remember that one is not evaluating the total flux but only the part of it on a small open surface of constant area whose distance from the source varies.

Comment: I guess it is important to understand the Gauss' theorem but if I am interested to draw lines around a point-like charge for example, I think I need to choose a region in which each point is perpendicular to the field according to Faraday's criterion. Of course if I am interested to the flux through an area of the space, it just doesn't matter what kind of area I consider.

Comment: Do you agree with my focus about the density of field lines? I am referring to the infinitesimal approach. Anyway thank you. I appreciate it, Giorgio. :-)